# Efficient method for reducing the precision of an array of numbers using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, precision

Using C#, what is an efficient method to reduce the precision of an array of floating point numbers by n digits without changing type?

Example:

```
float[]{1.34, 2.22, 2.32, 7.71}
```

becomes

```
float[]{1.00, 2.00, 2.00, 8.00}
```

or

```
float[]{1.30, 2.20, 2.30, 7.70}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.mathf.round?view=net-7.0

Comment: Write a loop that iterates over the array and rounds each item to the desired precision.  Or use [`ForEach<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.foreach?view=net-7.0),

Comment: Can you please define efficiency criteria?

Comment: I had guessed that iterating over the array and using the Round function would work. But it seemed too easy and I thought it might be inefficient.

Comment: Depends. It could be more efficient to get the data in the desired precision in the first place, it could be more efficient to round only on demand ... but regarding having an array of floats and have them all rounded down to a specific precision, then it's that.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I should have asked if that was generally considered the correct and reasonably efficient solution.

Comment: @Quantum_Kernel that is not inefficient. It has a time complexity of O(n) where `n` is the number of items in the array. If you use Release mode, the JIT compiler will optimise the loop using SIMD registers, which will be several times faster, but still O(n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cs
var array = new float[]{1.34f, 2.22f, 2.32f, 7.71f};

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    array[i] = MathF.Round(array[i], 1); // the second argument is the number of digits after the dot
}
```

That will modify the existing array and the result would be `float[]{1.30f, 2.20f, 2.30f, 7.70f}`

If you want to create a new array:

```cs
var array = new float[]{1.34f, 2.22f, 2.32f, 7.71f};
var roundedArray = array.Select(x => MathF.Round(x, 1)).ToArray(); // or .ToList()
```